# Let's create a Stack Overflow blog

Tags: discussion, feature-request, blog

The [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com) is an interesting read and is a good way to highlight interesting topics within their community.

I think Stack Overflow would gain at least as much from having its own showcase on discussions of interest such as "Question of the Week", analysis of a particular hot topic, humourous discussion threads on questions or chats, or other such material.

I'd say there is plenty of material available on a weekly basis that could serve as a topic subject matter, but is there enough interest within the community to sustain a blog on a weekly basis, and do people feel that a blog would add to the community?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're in luck!  [Rebecca Chernoff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff) just posted [a blog.stackoverflow.com article](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) announcing a new site to organize community blogs and help a community get their blog started.  The site is:

**http://blogoverflow.com/**

... and there is a [Getting Started](http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/) article to get you going.  This certainly is the place to get it going, but it's going to need some definition and committed contributors to get moving.

Comment: That's all nice and stuff, but there doesn't appear to be anything to be done with it.  All I see is "hey, talk amongst yourselves about it" and that's it.  Also, *what about* blog.stackoverflow.com?  Is that going to be released back to SO?

Comment: @Won't its meant as the Area51 for Stack Exchange blogs. Once the community has proven they can keep the blog running, they get 'promoted' to the blog.*.SE domain AFAIK

Comment: @IvoFlipse: I know how to create a proposal on A51, but there does not appear to be such an option on BOF.

Comment: The analogy doesn't stretch that far. If you want a blog for SO, follow the guidelines mentioned in the blog post and [this MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/area-51-for-blogs). You can always ask me for more information on chat :-)