# Where can I find site community blogs?

Tags: support, faq, blog-overflow, blogging

At one point, [all sites had blogs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266747/amazing-all-sites-have-blogs), although this was [later discontinued](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291741/we-will-no-longer-be-hosting-blog-overflow) for the majority of sites. I've also heard that some stacks still run their own blogs!

Where can I find these site blogs?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Unofficial Site Blogs

- [An Eye on the Universe](https://aneyeontheuniverse.wordpress.com/) (Astronomy)
- [Language Learning Blog](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog)
- [One Minute Reviews](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/) (Literature)
- [The Retrocomputing Blog](https://retrocomputingblog.wordpress.com/)
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy Community Blog](https://thesffblog.com/)
- [TeX Talk](http://tex-talk.net/)
- [Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory) (Worldbuilding)
- [CGCC Blog](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgcc-blog)

### Blog Overflow Archives

- [Ask Different Community Blog](https://apple.blogoverflow.com/)
- [Arqade Community Blog](https://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/) (previously [Gaming Stack Exchange](https://gamingse.wordpress.com/))
- [Aviation Community Blog](https://aviation.blogoverflow.com)
- [Stack Exchange Bicycles Blog](https://Bicycles.blogoverflow.com)
- [Eschewmenical](https://Christianity.blogoverflow.com) (Christianity)
- [Stack Exchange Stats Blog](https://stats.blogoverflow.com)
- [Database Administrators Community Blog](https://dba.blogoverflow.com)
- [Home Improvement Blog](https://DIY.blogoverflow.com)
- [English Language & Usage Community Blog](https://english.blogoverflow.com)
- [Geographic Information Systems Blog](https://gis.blogoverflow.com)
- [Islam Community Blog](https://Islam.blogoverflow.com)
- [Mathematica Community Blog](https://Mathematica.blogoverflow.com)
- [Mathematics Community Blog](https://math.blogoverflow.com)
- [Photography Community Blog](https://photo.blogoverflow.com)
- [Seasoned Advice Community Blog](https://cooking.blogoverflow.com/)
- [IT Security Community Blog](https://security.blogoverflow.com/)
- [The Stack Exchange Sysadmin Blog](https://blog.serverfault.com/)
- [Programmers Community Blog](https://programmers.blogoverflow.com/)
- [Super User Community Blog](https://blog.superuser.com/)
- [CS Theory Community Blog](https://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/)