# The SSL certificate for the archived Stack Exchange Gaming Blog is invalid

Tags: bug, blog, ssl

I tried to visit the Stack Exchange Gaming Blog's archive today but was greeted by a classic SSL warning. Turns out, the certificate behind https://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/ is invalid as it is made for ***.stackexchange.com**.

While I understand that the blogs are now dead, it'd be nice if the archives could still be visited without having to explicitly accept the broken certificate.
[image: error message on Edge]

Comment: Hmmm likely the only way this would get fixed is moving all the blogs to a common URL where a single wildcard would work for all of them. But at that point, is breaking all links to those blogs really worth the HTTPS support? The secure redirects still wouldn't work because they still wouldn't have a valid certificate.

Comment: @animuson Dropping HTTPS or breaking the links is def something I'd hate to see. No HTTPS in 2021 is just not-done (plus it'd take a huge SEO hit) and breaking links isn't much different. Is requesting blog-specific (since it's only, what, ~20 or so archives) certificates possible? SE is already on LetsEncrypt so I figure all it takes is an extra renewal script.

Comment: Turns out this issue only affects the Arqade blog, as [all other blogs were hosted on the blogoverflow.com domain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339115/where-can-i-find-site-community-blogs) barring SF and SU. But I would say there's zero chance of adding an explicit entry for this to the certificate - that's something we've repeatedly declined doing in multiple contexts ever since we started HTTPS. I think the only solution here is to move it to blogoverflow.com with the others.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize arqade's blog was an outlier (I only found out about blogs today), I'll change the title accordingly.

Comment: @animuson I think that, along with redirecting the old links, is the perfect solution. Most of the old links were using insecure `http://`, so doing this won't cause the link to break. A similar thing is done today with old `http://meta.*.stackexchange.com` links: those work with no SSL error.

Comment: @animuson et al, note that Arqade is [currently using archive.org](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16494/28182) to provide links to the blog, in order to avoid the SSL issue. It would be good if we could migrate to blog overflow. Could/Should we [status-review] tag this to get it onto the backlog at least?