# Blog Overflow page is out-of-date

Tags: bug, chat, blog, blog-overflow

The blogs aren't used much<sup>[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244467/269301)</sup>. The [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs) dedicated to the blogging system isn't used much either<sup>[2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19193662#19193662)</sup>. That's unfortunate, but sometimes experiments fail. Moving on.

[The website](http://blogoverflow.com/no-blog-yet.html) you're directed to when trying to enter a not-yet existing blog has no knowledge of this<sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB9FU.png)</sup>:

> #### The blog you are looking for has not been started yet.
>
> We are happy to provide resources for communities that want to supplement their site with a blog and show active interest from community members that are willing to contribute.
>
> For more information on what Blog Overflow is about and how to start a community blog, please [read our blog entry.](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow)
>
> There is a dedicated [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs) to help you get started and run your community blog. Feel free to drop in and say hi!

I'm not sure whether this is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), but could the site be updated with the current status?

To the best of my knowledge there is no longer a chat and no possibility to open a new blog. The current information is misleading.