# BlogOverflow text overflow

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, blog-overflow

I checked out [this blog post on Arqade](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2014/04/the-thousand-and-one-revisions-of-links-awakening/) and clicked on the [OP's name](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/author/Morwenn/) to find the overflowng text:

[image]

Comment: Blog Overflow is actually going to be shutting down completely soon, so it doesn't make sense for us to invest time in fixing any bugs for it. We'll be reaching out to all the individual communities who currently have a blog on their site's Meta over the coming weeks to discuss whether they want to let their blog die or transfer it to an alternate blogging platform and maintaining it on their own, as [Worldbuilding does now](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/we-have-a-blog). Those Meta posts will contain more detailed information than I've provided here.

Comment: @animuson maybe add a banner saying "this site is going to be shut down soon" there? Looks like people are still visiting, and better try and prepare them. (Currently there's no hint of the nearing shut down)

Comment: @animuson - We have a pretty active blog over in our community at Science Fiction and Fantasy. Are you saying that we would have to use an entirely third-party platform? Also, what would happen to the existing posts?

Comment: @Adamant I would say we have the only active community blog, as we are always in the #1 spot and have at least 1 new post a month, where as  the rest are lucky to have 1 a year.

Comment: @animuson A few of us at SF/F are trying to migrate our (rather active) community blog away from blogoverflow now, in advance of any changes... do you know if we'd be allowed to use the theme elements (images, CSS, etc) that was done for the site and/or blog on an off-site blog?

Comment: @KutuluMike As far as I know, the design team had no objections to that. They even offered to send higher quality images to help out when Worldbuilding was creating theirs (though I don't think they ever took them up on the offer). They may have found it too difficult to incorporate parts of their theme into an alternate platform. You'll want to have a separate conversation on your Meta about the design, and we can ping a designer to have a look at your requests.

Comment: @animusion WB didn't take up the offer originally, but we've asked again more recently so we can incorporate our new design.

Comment: @animuson SF/F has also set up an off-site blog so we can start working out the kinks while blogoverflow is still running. We're using hosted wordpress; we're kinda hoping we can get most or all of the WP theme itself. Who would we talk to about this?

Comment: @animuson actually, Worldbuilding has a pending request for a specific image that I assume will be answered at some point. :-)

Comment: @animuson: Wouldn't it be better to try and fix the problems Blog Overflow has (if any), rather than doing away with it entirely and send all the communities running off to disparate platforms?

Comment: @Robert they can't fix inactivity. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244467/were-no-longer-starting-new-individual-site-community-blogs-heres-why).