# Why doesn't anyone use the Stack Exchange community blogs anymore?

Tags: discussion, blog-overflow

Looks like activity is slowing down - do these blogs still get good readership, or is that not the direction Stack Exchange is going in?

Where is a good place to post thought leadership about the topics that Stack Exchange communities support?

Comment: The blogs are [about to shut down soon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285478/blogoverflow-text-overflow#comment925838_285478), so it's not relevant.

Answer (score 13):

[Science Fiction & Fantasy Blog](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/) is alive and well, although I only just learned of this announcement that the blogoverflow platform will be going away.

Looking at the main blog site, ours is the only really active blog (using blogoverflow.com), with new content appearing every few weeks. All the other ones seem to have 1-2 posts a year. Which is probably why they are dropping the service, because no one else is utilizing it. WorldBuilding.StackExchange has their own offsite blog (https://medium.com/universe-factory) and it appears to get a lot of new content as well.

If blogoverflow.com disappears we (as in Scifi.SE) will be moving our blog content to a third party as well.

Comment: I don't think this answer answers the question in title: Why doesn't anyone use the Stack Exchange community blogs anymore?

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong.