# Stack Exchange blog redirection issue

Tags: support, blog

Why http://blog.stackexchange.com redirects to https://stackoverflow.blog/? It is for any purpose or bug ?

Hope http://blog.stackexchange.com should be redirect to https://stackexchange.com/blogs right?

Comment: Those community blogs are shutting down soon.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So after that, https://stackoverflow.blog is the only blog will be available?

Comment: That is very true. Bottom line, SE decided to develop their own blog platform and ditch WordPress. And their internal blog platform probably can't support, or would require too much maintenance cost, for community blogs.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Oh, ho. Not aware of that. Is there any announcement regarding this in SE or any where?

Comment: Only [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285478/blogoverflow-text-overflow#comment925838_285478), but turns out it's [no big surprise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244467/were-no-longer-starting-new-individual-site-community-blogs-heres-why).