# Stack Exchange topic-specific blog posting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, blog

Does Stack Exchange support user blogs for specific topics or is this currently in development? Users with expertise in specific areas may have the desire to write a blog post teaching a particular topic. This would create a more stable foundation for user learning in established areas, pushing questions to be more focused on the cutting-edge where consensus hasn't been established, promoting discussion, development, and progress in the relevant areas.

Comment: There used to be community blogs, but no more. See [We're no longer starting new individual site Community Blogs - here's why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244467/307988) and [We will no longer be hosting Blog Overflow](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741)

Comment: If people want to write a blog, there's nothing preventing them from doing so on one of dozens of existing platforms and linking to them from their user profile. In fact, many already do this.

Comment: The wording of this question sounds like you're not specifically proposing a blog, but actually something else. Ehm... dare I say it? It's the dreaded D word!

Answer (score 12):

No, Stack Exchange is not intended to be a blogging platform and does not fundamentally support the publication of stand-alone, unsolicited "articles" in the context you typically associate with the traditional blogging format (more on that in a moment).

The fundamental unit of work on this site is created by asking a very specific question (a specific problem statement) you likely encounter in your day to day work or study — something that can be answered ***collectively*** and *definitively* in the space of a post. The collective answers are then vetted, improved, and sorted so the best stuff rises to the top, etc, etc. The curation of that content *collectively* is how we help and teach folks who come after.

However, Stack Exchange *does* have a facility called **self-answered questions** which provides a *bit* of blog-like functionality where folks can post interesting solutions they've encountered in their work by posting it in a self-answered Q&A format. Essentially, it allows folks to post both the problem statement (as a question) and the solution they arrived at (as an answer) without feigning a call for help to the community (the question is already answered and folks are still free to add answers of their own).

But the self-answered functionality isn't really meant to implement the role of a traditional blogging platform. The "articles" we allow here still need to adhere to fundamental qualities of a very specific problem statement (completely answerable in the space of a post), while a blog post often delves into broader exercises in pedagogy (broader concepts and teaching). For example, you couldn't publish a blog post here called "10 Ways to Avoid the Pitfalls of Collaboration" or "How to Learn C# in 24 hours". Even if those subjects are 100% completely on topic for the site, that type of broader pedagogy is not well supported nor allowed by our Stack Exchange format.

Answer (score 6):

To supplement [Robert's definitive answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306559/162102), some SE sites used to have blogs, but [SE discontinued them in 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741/162102) after a longer period of not creating any new ones.  However, a few sites kept their blogs, moving them off-site, and there's at least one site blog that was never official to begin with (was always off-site).  **If your content fits into the scope of a site that still has a blog**, you could try submitting your work there.  I would expect to find posts about blogs on the per-site metas of sites that have them.

According to the announcement discontinuing official blogs and comments there, the following sites have blogs:

- Information Security
- TeX / LaTeX
- Server Fault
- Science Fiction & Fantasy
- Worldbuilding

There might be more.