# Proposal for a new section for independent research of users

Tags: feature-request

I don’t know whether this idea has already been proposed in the past, but looking at the site carefully, I don’t thinks so.

For each sub-site (like Stack Overflow, Cross Validated, etc.) you have a unique section where users can post questions and receive answers. Do you think it could be a good idea to add a section (like Cross Validated Research Area, or Mathematics Stack Exchange Research Area) where users can post their research and findings instead of posting questions only? That is an area where users can post answers to unsolicited questions that they ask themselves and have a relevance to subjects in the corresponding area.

This is already a wonderful place where to exchange ideas and knowledge. But maybe that addition could have the potential to elevate it further and transform it into a place where people release their own research, or simply share some findings by writing short unsolicited articles for a potentially interested and specialized audience. That, for convenience, may be restricted to reputable users.

Comment: Yanno, we can do that already. There's even a check box for answering your own questions...

Comment: Yes I agree that we can post a question of which we already know the answer and immediately post also the answer, but it’s likely mixed with the other world of questions.. for example last day I answered one of my question, ok, but that was a “real” question left unanswered by the users (that I answers 2 days later because I found the answer).. I was thinking more of a section like “user articles”/“user publications” where users can write something for the community.. like a mini blog.. and as such separate it from the user’s “real questions” seeking an answer from the community.

Answer (score 4):

The Stack Exchange network provides great focused Q&A on its Main sites, and these include permitting and encouraging self-answered questions.

Each site also supports a Meta site and at least one chat room, and in the past many had a blog.

It is the high quality Q&A that I believe attracts visitors and users to our sites and I do not perceive a need to dilute this with an additional "area where users can post answers to unsolicited questions that they ask themself" because that is already possible by posting and self-answering their own questions.

I think that your feature request may distil to asking whether each site can get a blog, which I think has already been tried and for many sites failed - see [We're no longer starting new individual site Community Blogs - here's why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244467).

Comment: And personal blogs as a high reputation privilege was talked about..